# Powershell byte array to hex

Tags: arrays, powershell, encryption, byte, aes

I have the following byte array that I would like to obtain hex format in order to decrypt an encrypted string using aes-256-ecb. (PowerShell uses AES encryption if you specify key argument in `ConvertFrom-SecureString` function)

```
0 54 0 48 0 49 0 99 0 48 0 98 0 97 0 45 0 50 0 50 0 97 0 57 0 45 0 49 0 49 0 101
```

In order to check this I verify by using openssl:

```
echo 'mysecretdata' | openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -K 303534303438303439303939303438303938303937303435303530303530303937303537303435303439303439303130310a
```

**hex string is too long
invalid hex key value**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 29):

You can use the `X2` format string on each individual byte to get it's hex representation, then use the `-join` operator to concatenate the strings:

```
$bytes = 0,54,0,48,0,49,0,99,0,48,0,98,0,97,0,45,0,50,0,50,0,97,0,57,0,45,0,49,0,49,0,101
$hexString = ($bytes|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''
```

(If that's your actual key, you might want to refrain from ever using it again, now that it's public knowledge ;-) )

Comment: Thank you Mathias! now the hex key value seems correct but now I see a decryption error. bad decrypt
140097927906968:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:
ծGPQ3¬S/2d)k~Jjz+-

Comment: From your example it looks like you're trying to decrypt the plaintext (which doesn't make sense) and supplying the ciphertext as the key

Comment: Actually I am trying to use this string (previous one was just an example):  $echo 76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AHoATQBZAEMAVgAyAG4ATQBOAGIAZABRAHIAMAA0AEUANgBKAFUAUABXAHcAPQA9AHwAYQAzADkANAAwADMAMQAzAGMAMgA1AGUAZAAxAGQAZQA1ADUAZgA2AGEAMgA2ADQAYQA2ADAAZQA5AGYANQBjAGEANgBkAGYAZQA1ADkAYQA5AGIANgBmAGYAYgBjADQAZgBiADcAMABiADAAYgBhADQAMABkADIAMAA3AGEAZgA= | openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -K 0036003000310063003000620061002D0032003200610039002D003100310065
)2Ap@$
bad decrypt
140645963531928:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`string System.BitConverter::ToString(byte[] value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_BitConverter_ToString_System_Byte___) static method if you're fine with hyphenation:

```powershell
PS> $bytes = 0,7,14,21,28,35,42
PS> [System.BitConverter]::ToString($bytes)
00-07-0E-15-1C-23-2A
PS>
PS> # If you'd like to use this in a pipeline:
PS> ,$bytes | % { [System.BitConverter]::ToString($_) }
00-07-0E-15-1C-23-2A
PS>
PS> # If you can't obtain a byte[]-compatible input:
PS> $bytes | . { [System.BitConverter]::ToString(@($input)) }
00-07-0E-15-1C-23-2A
```

The [comma operator (`,`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-) makes sure that your byte array (or object castable to such) is passed in (via [`ForEach-Object` (`%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) running the script block over a 1-element array) as it is, and not iterated over.

If that's unavoidable, then the latter example uses the [dot sourcing operator (`.`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#dot-sourcing-operator-), a script block, and the [array subexpression operator (`@( )`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#array-subexpression-operator--) to collect the items from the [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6#piping-objects-to-functions) automatic function variable (an [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8), *not* [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8)) and produce an array `ToString`'s happy with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic way to convert a byte-array into a HexString:

```
$array  = [byte[]](1..15)
$hexbin = [System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary]::new()
$hexbin.Value = $array
$hexString = $hexbin.ToString()
```

gives this result:
0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F

and into the other direction it goes like this:

```
$bytes = [System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary]::Parse($hexString).Value
```

In your original question I dont see an array at all, but an AES256 key must be exact 32 bytes long (represented by a 64-characters hexstring). Your hexsting has a length of 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

While the currently most upvoted answer here suggests using the pipeline, I suggest using the ForEach method like so:

```
$bytes = -split '0 54 0 48 0 49 0 99 0 48 0 98 0 97 0 45 0 50 0 50 0 97 0 57 0 45 0 49 0 49 0 101' -as 'byte[]'
$hexString = -join $bytes.ForEach('ToString','X2')  # for a lowercase string, use 'x2' instead of 'X2'
```

You can read more about how I use `ForEach` here from this detailed breakdown of the ForEach & Where methods provided by this [powershellmagazine.com article](https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/#:%7E:text=ForEach%28string%20methodName%29%20and,object%5B%5D%20arguments%29) <sub><sup>([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230925202515/https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/#:%7E:text=ForEach%28string%20methodName%29%20and,object%5B%5D%20arguments%29)) ([archive.today](https://archive.today/AYRjK#:%7E:text=ForEach%28string%20methodName%29%20and,object%5B%5D%20arguments%29))</sup></sub>. Alternatively, here's a trimmed down version of the relevant section that I came up with:

> ###### ForEach(string methodName) / ForEach(string methodName, object[] arguments)
>
> Provide the method name as the first argument; any proceeding arguments provided will be passed to that method.
>
> ```
> $str = 'Foo', 'BAR', 'loRem', 'ipsum'
>
> # Output each string as lowercase
> $str.ForEach('ToLower')
> ```
>
> ```
> $dt = [datetime]'2023-01-04', [datetime]'2022-04-12', [datetime]'2021-10-30'
>
> # Output with a year deducted from each date
> $dt.ForEach('AddYears',-1)
> ```

---

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a "hex byte string" representation of a byte array, specifically  a separator-less concatenation of 2-hex-digits-per-byte string representations, such as `'090AFF'` for a byte array with (decimal) values `9`, `10`, and `255`

To offer **.NET API-based solutions** - as an alternative to the PowerShell-native solutions offered - which are both more convenient and perform better:

- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** / .NET 5+: Use [`[Convert]::ToHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToHexString) (and [`[Convert]::FromHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.FromHexString)), which directly support converting  to (and from) the desired "hex byte string" format, i.e. a separator-less string of 2-hex-digits-per-byte representations.

  ```bash
    # PowerShell 7+ only.

    [byte[]] $bytes = 9, 10, 255

    # -> '090AFF'
    [Convert]::ToHexString($bytes)
  ```
- In ***Windows PowerShell***: Use [`[BitConverter]::ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToString), but invariably uses `-` separation; however, you can easily strip these separators by appending `-replace '-'`

  ```bash
    # Windows PowerShell (too).

    [byte[]] $bytes = 9, 10, 255

    # -> '090AFF'
    [BitConverter]::ToString($bytes) -replace '-'
  ```