# powershell query of sys.sql_logins

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying automate some queries and am querying sys.sql_logins and get different results between a query in ssms and powershell.

My query is this:

```
$SQLquery =@" 

Select 'sql_logins' [sql_logins], @@SERVERNAME [Hostname], DB_NAME() [Database], * from sys.sql_logins;
"@
```

When I run that from a query in ssms i the SID result as 0xA1E3(some long alphanumeric string).  When i run the same thing via powershell - i get a complete different format for the SID.  Instead of the long alphanumeric string I end up with something like this {123, 45, 70, 16...} and i have no idea why or how to make it match the result i get via a manual query in ssms.

why does it change?  how do i get it to NOT change and remain like 0xA1E3(super long alphanumeric string)?

[edit - as requested]

Really not doing anything special to get or display the data.  `Invoke-sqlcmd` and then spit it out once returned.

```
$result = invoke-sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -serverinstance $computername -database $dbname -Username $dbuser -Password $dbpass


$result | Format-Table -Property Hostname, Database, name, principal_id, sid,`
type, type_desc, is_disabled, create_date, modify_date,`
default_database_name, default_language_name, credential_id,`
is_policy_checked, is_expiration_checked, password_hash -Autosize
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include how exactly you are running the query and using the output. Looks like the PSH version is converting hex into decimals automatically.

Comment: This is a presentation difference. The SID is a byte array. In SSMS byte arrays are displayed as hex string, while in PowerShell the default view is a comma separated list of byte values surrounded with brackets. If you want to format it, take a look at [Powershell byte array to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301473/powershell-byte-array-to-hex) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is correctly identified in another answer to this question in that the varbinary value being returned from the query is being treated as a byte array by powershell. My recommendation as to a fix is different, though - change the formatting in the query. If I change your query to:

```
Select 'sql_logins' [sql_logins], 
   @@SERVERNAME [Hostname], 
   DB_NAME() [Database], 
   convert(varchar(172), sid, 1) as sid 
from sys.sql_logins;
```

And then run it through the rest of your code, it works for me. NB: I didn't do `select *` in my query - if you really need all of the columns, you should list them explicitly. Lastly, one observation - `sys.sql_logins` is a server-level DMV; querying it on a per-database basis is going to be duplicative for all databases on the same server.

---

Edit - changed the length of the `varchar` to accommodate the `varbinary(85)` SID as [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says. Showing my work, (85 bytes * 2 characters/byte) + (2 characters for '0x') = 172.

Comment: I had to use convert(varchar(100) , sid, 1) for Azure SQL Database as the SID was getting truncated using varchar(50)

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 - good call out. I've edited the answer to accommodate the largest possible SID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SID which you get on the result window of SSMS is [a 16 byte (binary(16)) literal value based on a GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments), while the one which you get in PowerShell is as mentioned in the comments, a default view is a comma separated list of byte values surrounded with brackets. PowerShell is better at string manipulation than SQL Server hence it internally converts the binary(16) value to a byte value.

Here is what you can do -

```
$SQLquery = "Select 'sql_logins' [sql_logins], @@SERVERNAME [Hostname], DB_NAME() [Database], * from sys.sql_logins;"
$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -ServerInstance ServerName -Database master
$Result[0].sid
```

`$Result[0].sid.Length` would give you 1024, implying that the length is indeed a KB. Use the `ConvertTo-SQLHashString` function from [Mike Fal's](https://stackexchange.com/users/132891/mike-fal) blog where he talks about copying SQL Logins via PowerShell -

```
function ConvertTo-SQLHashString{
  param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $binhash)
  $outstring = '0x'
  $binhash | ForEach-Object {$outstring += ('{0:X}' -f $_).PadLeft(2, '0')}
  return $outstring
}

ConvertTo-SQLHashString $Result[0].sid
```

That would give you a long hex value. You could use the PowerShell `TrimEnd()` function to get the results like those in SSMS window -

```
(ConvertTo-SQLHashString $Result[0].sid).TrimEnd('0')
```