# Reverse hex dump to a zip file in windows (powershell)

Tags: powershell, reverse, zip, hexdump

I'm new to data handling, so I'm not even sure this is possible, but I would like to make a zipfile from a hex dump. The first hex numbers in the hex dump are `50 4b 03 04` indicating that the format is a zipfile, but there seems to be txt files as well, so I am a bit confused on how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried using `cat $file | xxd -r -p > file.zip` in WSL? `xxd` is a utility to work with hex.

Comment: In terms of powershell, there are utilities to work with hex [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301473/powershell-byte-array-to-hex)

Comment: It worked out, found this gem; https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/.

Comment: That’s more of a yes it works, but using web instead of cli, which was part of the question