# What format is this data in - CSVDE export - Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, csvde

I am at a loss here.  I am trying to make sense of CSVDE and how it works.  When I export a user, for my application, I need to make sure I get the objectSID.  When I run CSVDE I get the following objectSID:

X'010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000'

When I use powershell and dump the same user, I get this as the objectSID

150000052100024321021079141206121462716544143151400

Obviously, these aren't the same string of characters.  I need some way to dump user from Active Directory and get the objectSID in the format of X'010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000' without using CSVDE.

Has anyone seen this before and do any of you have anything that can help me figure this out?  I thought I could get the Powershell output and then convert it but I have no idea what format that data is in.  I've seen some people say the CSVDE output is binary (but its not) and I have seen some say it is hex (I dont think so).  So I am at a loss.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: What are you using to "dump" the user? Is that a decimal representation of the SID? It does appear to be a hex value that you're after, as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution, but I can tell you **how the two representations relate to each other**:

> `X'010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000'`

The string inside `'...'` is a "hex byte string",  composed of `0`-left-padded 2-*hex*-digit representations of byte values.

You can convert it to a `[byte[]]` array as follows:

```bash
[byte[]] $bytes = 
  -split (
    "X'010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000'" `
      -replace "^X'|'$" -replace '..', '0x$& '
  )
```

`-replace "^X'|'$"` strips the `X'` prefix and the `'` suffix from the input string; for an explanation of the core to-byte-conversion technique, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065438/45375).

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), a new .NET API allows for a simplification (more on that in the bottom section):

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only.
[byte[]] $bytes = 
  [Convert]::FromHexString(
    "X'010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000'" `
      -replace "^X'|'$"
  )
```

---

> `150000052100024321021079141206121462716544143151400`

The above is the - useless due to being *ambiguous* - stringification of the *decimal* representations of the byte values from the original string *without* padding, as obtained via the following:

```bash
-join $bytes
```

---

In PowerShell, given its rich .NET type support, you may not need to deal with *string* representations of raw byte arrays.

However, if you do need to create an *unambiguous* string representation, you need to either use byte representations *padded to a fixed with* - as in the input string - or *use a separator*; e.g.:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only.
# 2-hex-digit padding
# -> '010500000000000515000000f3d2d24f8dce0c921ba52c8f97040000'
[Convert]::ToHexString($bytes)

# Windows PowerShell (too)
# 2-hex-digit + "-"-separation; to strip the latter, use:
#    [BitConverter]::ToString($bytes) -replace '-'
# -> '01-05-00-00-00-00-00-05-15-00-00-00-F3-D2-D2-4F-8D-CE-0C-92-1B-A5-2C-8F-97-04-00-00'
[BitConverter]::ToString($bytes)
```

Note:

- The [`[Convert]::ToHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToHexString) (and [`[Convert]::FromHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.FromHexString)) .NET APIs are only available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)
- [`[BitConverter]::ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToString) works in *Windows PowerShell* too, but invariably uses `-` separation; however, you can easily strip these separators by appending `-replace '-'` or switch to a different separator, with, say, `-replace '_', ','`

Comment: Assuming the OP already has the byte representation in a variable in their code they can generate the desired string with ```$csvde = "X'" + (($bytes | foreach-object { $_.ToString("X2") }) -join '') + "'"``` (other options for the bytes-to-hex part here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301473/powershell-byte-array-to-hex as well)

Comment: Thanks, @mclayton - there are simpler solutions using .NET APIs. I've updated the answer accordingly and have also posted an answer at the linked post. Additionally, I've streamlined the _from_-string conversion.