# Issues in getting right value of SID

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I am trying to implement active geo-replication using Azuresql (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal?view=azuresql&tabs=portal)

In order to setup the cross-subscription geo-replication there are few t-sql commands (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal?view=azuresql&tabs=portal#cross-subscription-geo-replication) that needs to be run. Due to certain security concerns I am converting the t-sql commands to equivalent poweshell script and trying to execute through the Azure DevOps pipeline.

On running the below script I am getting sid value which is not hexadecimal. It returns a data with datatype System.Array. I again tried to convert the data to hexadecimal value but it does seem to match.

```
try {

$server = "YourServerName"
$database = "master"
$username = "testadmin"
$password = "testpassword"
$query1 = "create login geodrsetup with password = 'ComplexPassword01';"
$query2 = "create user geodrsetup for login geodrsetup;alter role dbmanager add member geodrsetup;"
$query3 = "select sid from sys.sql_logins where name = 'geodrsetup';"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $quer1 -Username $username -Password $password -Verbose

Write-Host "Login Added Successfully"
 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $query2 -Username $username -Password $password -Verbose

Write-Host "User Added Successfully"
 
$result=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $query3 -Username $username -Password $password -Verbose -AS DATATABLES

Write-Host "Get SID vaule"
 
$test= $result.sid
 
Write-Host $test -ForegroundColor Green

foreach ($item in $test) {
    # Convert the item to hexadecimal and concatenate it to the existing string
    $hexString += "{0:X}" -f $item
}
 
# Output the concatenated hexadecimal string
Write-Output $hexString

}
catch {
    $_.Exception | Format-List -Force
}
```

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: Please, show us (in the question) the actual values of `$Result.sid`), the type (`$Result.sid.PSTypeNames`) and how you would expect that specific value would be displayed.

Comment: Thanks @iRon for your response. When I tried directly using t-sql command the actual value is 0x01060000000000640000000000000000B3A911799B43C040AD69D2B74B9A8588 but while executing it via powershell I am getting  1 6 0 0 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 179 169 17 121 155 67 192 64 173 105 210 183 75 154 133 136. $Result.sid.PSTypeNames is returning System.Array , System.Object[], System.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer your byte array to a hex string:
<sub>(this question is in fact a duplicate with: [Powershell byte array to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46301473/1701026))</sub>

```
# $Bytes = [Bytes[]]$Result.Sid
$Bytes = [Bytes[]]@(1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 169, 17, 121, 155, 67, 192, 64, 173, 105, 210, 183, 75, 154, 133, 136)
'0x' + (($Bytes|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')

0x01060000000000640000000000000000B3A911799B43C040AD69D2B74B9A8588
```

But in case you actually looking for a real [security identifier (Sid)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier) representation:

```
[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($Bytes, 0).Value

S-1-100-0-0-2031200691-1086342043-3084020141-2290457163
```

Comment: Thanks once again @iRon for your response. I tested the first one and am getting error : Unable to find type [Bytes].
At line:1 char:11
+ $Bytes = [Bytes[]]@(1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
+           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Bytes:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound . In this case I am using Powershell verison: 5.1

Comment: Never mind the problem resolved now. It was a typo mistake. Thanks a lot @iRon for your help